# MySQL Workbench EER Diagram changing table colors

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

After I creating an EER diagram from an existing database I am unable to read the table names in the diagram due to the table header and the tablename text both being black.
I'm not sure why this is as it wasn't this way last time I used it.
Does anyone know if there is a way of changing the colors used in the diagram?
I've hunted through all the menus but nothing is obvious.
any pointers much appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Click on the table you want to change the color. Then on the left side, under the `properties editor` section you have a tab named `Properties` (tabs are positioned at the bottom of that area). Click on it and the first property you can modify is the color. The value should be entered in hexa :)

Comment: As a little update, in 5.2 version at least a color picker appear when clicked on it.

Comment: To see this panel (with properties and colors), drag the left edge of the Workbench window to the right.